# The width of button using default modena styles in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Take a look at the following image:

[image]

There are two elements on it - `Button` and `Label` with the **same** text.

Button has width `54 px`, lable has width `36 px`. The difference is: `54px - 36px = 18px`.

I've studied `modena.css but` still can't understand where these `18px` come from.

Could anyone explain?

Comment: `-fx-padding: 0.333333em 0.666667em 0.333333em 0.666667em; /* 4 8 4 8 */`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [current version of modena.css](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u60/rt/file/996511a322b7/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css), line 420, button has padding defined by

```css
-fx-padding: 0.333333em 0.666667em 0.333333em 0.666667em; /* 4 8 4 8 */
```

On windows, `0.6666667em` is 8 pixels, on a Mac it is slightly more, so that padding on the left and right sides accounts for the difference in width.

Comment: Could you explain `Mac it is slightly more`? I thought that javafx application on all OS must be pixel:pixel same, mustn't it?

Comment: @Pavel_K The units are `em`, not `px`. It's explained near the top of modena.css (lines 45-74 in the version I linked). Why on earth do you care about this anyway? "I thought that javafx application on all OS must be pixel:pixel same, mustn't it?" - no: where did you get that idea. It won't even be the same pixel size on the same OS, as in general it would depend on user preferences.